# Linq query to display a proper sort order

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Table 1: Lookups

```
LookUpID
LookUpName
Desc
DisplayOrder
```

Table 2: BillingRates

```
BillingRateID
BillingRate
ClientID
LookupID
```

I want the lookup name to be displayed (sort by Bill rate)

```
DataContext DataContext1 = new DataContext1(AppSettings.ConnectionString);

return ( from Lookups in DataContext1.Lookups
         join BillingRates in DataContext1.BillingRates
         on  Lookups.LookupID equals BillingRates.LookupID
         orderby BillingRates.BillingRate
         select new
         {
             Lookups.LookupID,
             Lookups.LookupName,
             Lookups.Desc
         }).Distinct();
```

It gave me all the row, so I used Distinct(); The lookup Name is still not based on billing rate.

I am new to LINQ. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `BillingRates.BillingRate` (int, string, double, etc.)?

Comment: This might be a (human) language problem, but I'm having some trouble following what you ask. "It gave me all the row" : "all *of* the row" (all columns) or "all the row*s*" (several rows)? And what's the declared return value of that function, as you are returning an Enumerator over an anonymous type?

Comment: billingRates.BillingRate is decimal. It gives me all the rows for example the lookupName Architect is displayed for each billing rate. I need only one row with maximum billing rate.

Comment: James Curran I apologize for the language problem. I will be more cautious in future.

Comment: @Kalls: Not a problem (Really -- read some of my messages here, and you might not believe English is my native language....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do the `OrderBy` at the end?

```
return (from Lookups in DataContext1.Lookups 
     join BillingRates in DataContext1.BillingRates 
     on  Lookups.LookupID equals BillingRates.LookupID 
     select new 
     { 
         Lookups.LookupID, 
         Lookups.LookupName, 
         Lookups.Desc,
         BillingRates.BillingRate
     })
     .GroupBy(x => x.LookupID)
     .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(x => x.BillingRate).First())
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.BillingRate);
```

**EDIT:** I am kind of confused but try the following and let me know if that helps.

Comment: This is displaying multiple lookup names and multiple BillingRate for example architect 0.75 architect 1.00 architect 1750.00 I only wanted the one look up name based on maximum value. In the above mentioned case it is 1750.00

Comment: billingRates.BillingRate is decimal. It gives me all the rows for example the lookupName Architect is displayed for each billing rate. I need only one row with maximum billing rate.

Comment: Wow that is some complex Linq Code and I am learning from you. The above code works in LinqPad. I am sure it works fine when I integrate that in to my project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have a foreign key relationship set up, LINQ will create the join for you automatically, so it would be just:

```
 DataContext1.Lookups.Max(LkUp => LkUp.BillingRate.BillingRate)
```

Otherwise, (with the explicit join)

```
return ( from Lookups in DataContext1.Lookups   
     join BillingRates in DataContext1.BillingRates   
     on  Lookups.LookupID equals BillingRates.LookupID 
     orderby BillingRates.BillingRate desc
     select new   
     {   
         Lookups.LookupID,   
         Lookups.LookupName,   
         Lookups.Desc,  
         BillingRates.BillingRate  
     }).First();
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type AnonymousType #1 to System.Linq.IQueryable Error. This code is called from C# method that returns IQueryable

Comment: Sorry That I am not clear.here is sample data returned     Architect  0.0
Architect  1.0
Architect  1750.00
PM 1.0
PM 2.0
PM 3500.00

I want results

PM 3500.00
Architect 1750.00  First only gave me one row.